# PHP check if string is in a variable

Tags: php

I am using this code:

```
preg_match("/^.*\[Ticket ID\: \#(\d*)\].*$/", $subject, $output_array);
$ticketnumber = $output_array[1];
```

which echoes out the number in strings like:

```
[Ticket ID: #1234]
```

in the $subject variable and puts it into the `$ticketnumber` variable

how can i check if `[Ticket ID: #1234]` exists in the subject variable or not?

Comment: can't you use gettype() ?

Comment: what are you trying to check if exists? the output from your preg_match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to figure out if the ticketnumber exists in the provided subject.

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

// input
$subject = "[Ticket ID: #1234]";

// parse
preg_match("/^.*\[Ticket ID\: \#(\d*)\].*$/", $subject, $output_array);
$ticketnumber = isset($output_array[1]) ? intval($output_array[1]) : null;

// validate
if ($ticketnumber)
{
    // A ticket number was found in subject
}
else
{
    // not found
}

?>
```

Comment: could i use your above code with if(!$ticketnumber) { ... ?

Comment: yes you can, that will the reverse of my validate code above.

Answer (score 0):

try [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/strpos):

example:

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```

in your scenario you need to try like this:

```
 $findme='[Ticket ID: #1234]';
 $pos = strpos($subject, $findme);
if($pos){
 //it  contains
}
else {
//not containing
}
```